# Event lat/lng mismatch AJAX success data lat/lng

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I want to retrieve the correct **lat**/**lng** when the Google Maps marker finishes drag.

But for the same exact point it gives two different (very approximate) coordinates.

### Example results for the same drop:

`evt.latLng`: *39.82213542984826, -7.484207724853491*

`data.results[0].geometry.location`: *39.822158, -7.484110899999998*

The code used to get these results:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    $.getJSON({
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + evt.latLng.lat() + "," + evt.latLng.lng() + '&key=ABC',
        data: {},
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (data.status == "OK") {
                $('#div').html(evt.latLng.lat() + ", " + evt.latLng.lng() + '<br />' + data.results[0].geometry.location.lat + ', ' + data.results[0].geometry.location.lng)
            }
        }
    });
});
```

So my question is, why the difference and which one provides the most accurate coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `latLng` object on the `dragend` event is where you dropped the pin, and it represents the location you want to find the closest mapped address to.

> **latlng** — The latitude and longitude values specifying the location for which you wish to obtain the closest, human-readable address.

The data in the response contains the nearest addresses found (or something less specific if not found, e.g. town/city) for those coordinates. In your case, the address at the first index of the response, which will be the most accurate result, is not exactly where the coordinates of your pin is.

If you look at the full JSON response, it will become a bit clearer.

[image: JSON]

> **Note:** Reverse geocoding is an estimate. The geocoder will attempt to find the closest addressable location within a certain tolerance. If no match is found, the geocoder will return zero results.

**Source:** [Reverse Geocoding for a Latitude/Longitude](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse).

You can read a bit more on the topic here, which includes an example.

Comment: So `geometry.location` gives the exact coordinates where the marker was dropped and `evt.latLng` gives the closest, human-readable address? I couldn't understand the purpose of lat/lng in `geometry.location` on your answer. Also i would like to add that `data.results[0].formatted_address` is a full-readable address.

Comment: The other way round. `evt.latLng` is where you dropped the pin. `data.results[0].geometry.location` is the coordinates of the nearest actual address found.

Answer (score 0):

The geocode funtion return the  position  of the road  (or the center of the road or others accessible place ) closer to the demands coordinates.. in some cause the result si pratically the same that the request  .. sometimes .. not .. you ealsy test this condition  .. clicking (dragging) on a not accessible area .. and see the result  .. is some case as when  drag over a river or a not accessible aree you can see difference for many meters  or more  .